# Prevent Windows from downloading updates when using wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-update

Is there any way to disable Windows Update from trying to download updates when using a wifi connection or tethered through a phone? On slow wifi connections, having Windows Update hog part of the bandwidth slows browsing down a lot, and sometimes when tethering I'm paying according to amount of data transferred.

Comment: PS - I'm not interested in switching to manual updates, that would be cumbersome.

Comment: How about stopping the Windows Update service from the Windows Services Panel when using a Wi-Fi connection? I don't think there is a way Windows update can identify how you've connected to the internet and decide to download updates or not.

Comment: @Thomas: I could, but on my netbook it takes incredibly long to call up the Windows Update center and cancel the download. Windows *should* know the active adapter being used for the connection right, because it does inform the user about that in systray.

Comment: PPS - Perhaps there's a standalone software for this, if there isn't built-in support?

Answer (score 1):

Use your anti-virus/firewall software to do this. For example, in Kaspersky, each network can have firewall rules where you can enable and disable applications allowed on that specific network connection.